# One method accessible to all controllers - where to put it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In MVC, for example I have 5 different controller files. In all of them I have a method for saving an image. Is there a way to put this method on one place and every controller method to access it, instead of writing it in every controller?
I tried

```
 MyController.MyMethod();
```

But the Intellisence isn't showing it after I write the dot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put it in a utility class and make it static. From your controllers all you need to do is something like:

```
Utility.SaveImage(...);
```

Comment: Better adherence to SRP than using a base controller +1

Comment: @Icarus But where do I put that Utility class? In the Contents folder?

Comment: @Srcee I would put it in a separate folder. Typical names are: Utils, Common, Core, Shared, etc. I tend to follow Java conventions, if the class' namespace is Shared, then I'd put it in a folder called Shared, for example.

Comment: @Srcee i think that if we are talking about mvc here all such methods should go in the helper folder

Answer (score 8):

Use a base controller

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected virtual void MyMethod()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Then your controllers inherit your base controller

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        this.MyMethod();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could create a static helper class

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static void MyMethod()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}

public class HomeController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Helper.MyMethod()
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: No downvote or any such ... but think the resposibility of saving an image would be best placed in a class of it's own rather than a base controller. As per Icarus below

Comment: Agreed, for saving an image a helper class would be best. I was more focusing on the fact he wanted the method to be available to each controller (and not everything).